# How to provide Scripting support for Qt-Applications?

Tags: c++, qt, scripting

I'm looking for a scripting language which can be integrated into my Qt5 Application. The application has a public api, which can be used to extend the application with plugins. Now I want to add a scripting language to the application which provides access to the whole public api.
The scripting language must fulfill the following **Requirements**:

- Script Code can be executed from within the QT-Application.
- The user can access the file-system, network and create graphical elements from the scripting language.
- The user can access the public api of my QT Application through bindings.
- There should be a generator available to automatically generate script-language bindings for my public api.
- For classes that are part of the Public Api, it should be possible to pass around objects between the QT-Application and the Scripting Engine.

I evaluated the following Script-Languages:

- **Qt-Script**, together with the QT-Script Generator.
  The scripting language is based on ECMAScript/Javascript and can easily be integrated into QT apps. This fulfills all my requirements and works as expected. The generator can be used to generate bindings for the QT-Api itself and to generate bindings for the public api of my application. Sadly the qt-script module is going to be **deprecated** with qt5.5 and the scriptgenerator is **no longer maintained**.
- **Python**
  There seem to be several python-qt bindings available.
  Pyside would probably be ok, but it seems to be **inactive** as well. Apart from that I would have to embed python into c++, which is not supported by pyside out of the box, but could be done by the python c api.

What scripting-languages and tools do you suggest, that fulfills all my requirements?

Comment: QJSEngine and other QML classes replace Qt-Script and should be able to fulfill some (or all) of your requirements even if your application is not originally based on QML.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I read about that. But the functionality is really limited compared to qt-script. I doubt that the scriptgenerator could be modified to generate a comparable result (using qjsengine instead of qt-script).

Comment: As SaZ says: QML is *the* scripting environment for Qt at the moment. It even comes with a lot of bindings to existing Qt classes. And it allows your users to easily create new UIs!

Comment: QML does not fulfill all of my requirements. The user cannot access the filesystem and network out of the box. Futhermore only QObject based classes can be made available to the script engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) with Python seems to be a good choice. SWIG is still actively maintained.

Although SWIG doesn't fulfill all of my requirements out of the box, it shouldn't be that a big thing to make all of them work:

> Script Code can be executed from within the QT-Application.

This is not supported out of the box. You have to embed a python interpreter into your application. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

> The user can access the file-system, network and create graphical elements from the scripting language.

Accessing the filesystem and network should not be a problem with python. To create graphical userinterfaces, there are a lot of libraries available:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

> - The user can access the public api of my QT Application through bindings.
> - There should be a generator available to automatically generate script-language bindings for my public api.

This is done by SWIG. They provide great C++ and c++11 support.

- http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html
- http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html

> For classes that are part of the Public Api, it should be possible to
>   pass around objects between the QT-Application and the Scripting
>   Engine.

This is possible using the c++ functions provided by swig:

- *SWIG_TypeQuery* gets you information about C++ types
- *SWIG_NewPointerObj* converts a  c++ object to a python (proxy) object
- *SWIG_ConvertPtr* converts a python (proxy) object back to c++ object

More info in the [External runtime chapter](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Modules.html#Modules_external_run_time)